# solving recursion by asymptotic comutations

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

I would like to solve following equation:
$$T(1) = 0$$
$$T(n) = 2T(n/2) + \Theta(n^2)$$
$$T(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{{\log_2n}}2^i \Theta\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{2i}}\right)$$

Now, I would like to compute it, but I am newbie at asymptotic.  I only show you my approach (give good result), but I am not sure about corectness of computations:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{{\log_2n}}2^i \Theta\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{2i}}\right)=n^2\sum_{n=0}^{{\log_2n}} \Theta\left(\frac{2^i}{2^{2i}}\right)=n^2\sum_{n=0}^{{\log_2n}} \Theta\left(\frac{1}{2^{i}}\right)=n^2\cdot O(1) = \Theta(n^2)$$

Comment: Replacing the $\Theta$ formula by $$T(n)=2T(n/2)+A_n$$ with $$an^2-c\leqslant A_n\leqslant bn^2+c$$ for every $n$, for some positive $(a,b,c)$, should help you put your computations on some rock-solid ground. It might also help to notice that, rigorously speaking, the formula you propose should be interpreted as $$T(2^k)=2T(2^{k-1})+\Theta(2^{2k}).$$

Comment: Is it possible to make my computations correct ? Where Am I wrong ?

Comment: In a nut shell, tell me if my computations are correct (more or less formal), but correct ?

Comment: The conclusion that $T(2^k)=\Theta(2^{2k})$ is correct.

Comment: Could you refer to my computations, please ?

Comment: Could you refer to my first comment, please? (Do you think that I would have posted it if I thought the approach in your post was perfectly valid?)